# How to go about solving $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\sum _{n=0}^{499}\:\left(-1\right)^n\frac{x^{1+2n}}{\left(2n+1\right)!}\right)$

Tags: calculus

It showed up on today's worksheet and we're not quite sure where to start.
I have a general idea of "I need to find where the power series converges to then take the limit to infinity of that" but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

The end result is supposed to be something like Find $lim_{n→∞} p_{1000}(x)$. What can you say about $|p_{1000}(x) − sin x|$ for large values of x?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried? How about doing this problem with 499 replaced by 2? Then do it with 3 instead of 499.

Comment: @HansEngler Does that count?

Comment: It will give you insight. And do it with a partner and talk about it.

Comment: Since your mentioned sum has finite summands, change the order of $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ and summation. Notice that generally, changing the order of an infinite sum and limit is not allowed.

Comment: I guess you mean $\lim _{n \to \infty }\left(\sum _{m=0}^{n}\:\left(-1\right)^m\frac{x^{1+2m}}{\left(2m+1\right)!}\right)$, instead of the one you mensioned in the title of your question. Am I right?

Comment: @Finish not sure. As I said, we were given the limit in the question title, phrased exactly the same. I see your equation would have a radius of convergence of 0, but again, not sure where to go from there. Sorry this unit isnt making a ton of sense to me

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) has the first image example for for $\sin x$. What do you see happening?

Answer (score 1):

You have a polynomial in $x$ with leading term $-x^{999}/999!$. Do you know what happens with such polynomials as $x\to\infty$?

---

You say "I need to find where the power series converges" but there is no power series here since the sum stops at 500 terms.

Comment: no, not sure I do

Comment: The original function was sin(x). I represented it as a power series

Comment: Our TA gave us the limit in the question title. I'm just looking for guidance on finding it